# edmx on visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-mac

I'm working with EF 5 in visual studio mac. The same solution is working on Windows machine But in mac it is giving the error

System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException
Unable to load the specified metadata resource.

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): EntityFramework.

Exception stack trace:
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.LoadResources (System.String assemblyName, System.String resourceName, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[T] uriRegistry, System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver) [0x00075] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource..ctor (System.String originalPath, System.String assemblyName, System.String resourceName, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[T] uriRegistry, System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver) [0x0000d] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.CreateResourceLoader (System.String path, System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoader+ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, System.String validExtension, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[T] uriRegistry, System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver) [0x00038] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoader.Create (System.String path, System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoader+ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, System.String validExtension, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[T] uriRegistry, System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver) [0x00008] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoader.Create (System.String path, System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoader+ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, System.String validExtension, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[T] uriRegistry) [0x00009] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.SplitPaths (System.String paths) [0x00122] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2+<>c__DisplayClass2[TArg,TResult].b__0 () [0x00000] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2+Result[TArg,TResult].GetValue () [0x0002c] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2[TArg,TResult].Evaluate (TArg arg) [0x0007d] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.GetArtifactLoader (System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.DbConnectionOptions effectiveConnectionOptions) [0x00014] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.GetMetadataWorkspace (System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.DbConnectionOptions effectiveConnectionOptions) [0x00000] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace () [0x0000f] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.RetrieveMetadataWorkspaceFromConnection () [0x00014] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor (System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection connection, System.Boolean isConnectionConstructor, System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory objectQueryExecutionPlanFactory, System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator translator, System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory) [0x000ea] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor (System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection connection) [0x00000] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel () [0x00006] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel () [0x00006] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext () [0x0007c] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize () [0x00000] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ForceOSpaceLoadingForKnownEntityTypes () [0x0000f] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext () [0x00006] in <000f54522ad145bf987b3043022f9799>:0 
  at ODIR.DataAccess.EntityModel.OnlineDirectory_DevEntities.USP_GETUSERINFO (System.String username, System.String password) [0x0004b] in /Users/hanishmaram/WorkSpace/svn_projects/trunk/ODIR.DataAccess/EntityModel/DataRepository.Context.cs:69 
  at ODIR.DataAccess.UserContext.GetUserInfo (System.String username, System.String password) [0x0000a] in /Users/hanishmaram/WorkSpace/svn_projects/trunk/ODIR.DataAccess/Context/UserContext.cs:35 
  at ODIR.Controllers.HomeController.Index (System.String username, System.String password) [0x00007] in /Users/hanishmaram/WorkSpace/svn_projects/trunk/ODIR.Controllers/HomeController.cs:27 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:lambda_method (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase,object[])
  at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase controller, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] parameters) [0x00072] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] parameters) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod () [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39 (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) [0x00000] in :0 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.Web.Mvc.Async.EndInvokeDelegate`2[System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+ActionInvocation,System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult]:invoke_TResult_IAsyncResult_TState (System.IAsyncResult,System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker/ActionInvocation)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResult`2[TResult,TState].CallEndDelegate (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResultBase`1[TResult].End () [0x00029] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult] (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00007] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d () [0x00014] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+AsyncInvocationWithFilters+<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f () [0x00086] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32 (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResult`1[TResult].CallEndDelegate (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResultBase`1[TResult].End () [0x00029] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult] (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00007] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass21+<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c () [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00041] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResult`1[TResult].CallEndDelegate (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResultBase`1[TResult].End () [0x00029] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult] (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00007] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Web.Mvc.Controller+ExecuteCoreState innerState) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.Web.Mvc.Async.EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1[System.Web.Mvc.Controller+ExecuteCoreState]:invoke_void_IAsyncResult_TState (System.IAsyncResult,System.Web.Mvc.Controller/ExecuteCoreState)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncVoid`1[TState].CallEndDelegate (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResultBase`1[TResult].End () [0x00029] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult] (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00007] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15 (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Web.Mvc.Controller controller) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncVoid`1[TState].CallEndDelegate (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResultBase`1[TResult].End () [0x00029] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult] (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00007] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5 (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler+ProcessRequestState innerState) [0x00000] in :0 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.Web.Mvc.Async.EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1[System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler+ProcessRequestState]:invoke_void_IAsyncResult_TState (System.IAsyncResult,System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler/ProcessRequestState)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncVoid`1[TState].CallEndDelegate (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResultBase`1[TResult].End () [0x00029] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult] (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00007] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.async_handler_complete_cb (System.IAsyncResult ar) [0x00015] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web

Please let me know where the issue is happening in mac.